# How to add a header to an incoming HTTP request?

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a Connect middleware for node.js that needs to add an HTTP header to an incoming request.

Something like this seems to work:

```
function authorize_request(req, res, next) {
  //...
  req.headers['remote-user'] =  user;
  next();
}
```

The problem is that the request is an instance of `http.IncomingMessage`, and the headers property is [documented to be read only](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers):

Is this an allowed way of adding a header to a request or is it going to fail in some scenarios? Is there a better way?

Comment: There is no reason to edit the request headers, only response headers. Passing variables to other middlewares or other parts of your code should be done by another object placed on the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to pass some internal information to your next middleware, just use objects instead of actual headers.
It is not a good practice to modify headers, as other modules can rely on this, and it will mess them up.

```
function authorize(req, res, next) {
  // ...
  req.data = req.data || { };
  req.data.remoteUser = user;
  next();
}
```

Comment: Adding an attribute to the request object is a nice approach and it makes sense in my case. Although I can see some cases where modifying headers would be a reasonable thing to do (say a middleware that sanitizes a 'Host' header). Modifying/adding a header seems very similar to modifying a request path, which Connect supports.