# How can request headers be modified in nodejs

Tags: node.js, http

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524273/how-to-add-a-header-to-an-incoming-http-request) post and realize that what I want to do is bad but I have a client which is posting data without adding either Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding.  I can mimic the request in curl with:

`curl -H "Accept:" -H "Content-Type:"  -H "Expect:"  -H "Content-Length:"  -d 'hello=world' http://localhost:1337/post`

and adding the Transfer-Encoding header

`curl -H "Accept:" -H "Content-Type:"  -H "Expect:"  -H "Content-Length:" -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" -d 'hello=world' http://localhost:1337/post`

yields the expected POST data.

I'm running a server using node with the following code:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('chunk', chunk.toString());
  });

  req.on('end', function () {
    res.end();
  });
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Is there a place where I can intercept the request and add the header so I can access the data, or is there another method/event I can use to get to the POST data?

Thanks,
Shane Holder

Comment: You want to redirect the request to another url with additional/modified  headers, right?

Comment: I'd like to just consume the request with the body but if I need to redirect I could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% clear on what you are trying to do, but I think that I can point you in some useful directions here:

> Is there a place where I can intercept the request and add the header so I can access the data, or is there another method/event I can use to get to the POST data?

So the first thing to know is that the HTTP module is all available as source code. And it appears to be mostly [written in Javascript](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js). So if you don't mind some copy-pasting you can probably hack this a little bit.

The other useful tidbit is that HTTP module is just a fleshed out implementation of a socket that handles the HTTP. If you really want to, you can drop down the socket level and process all of the incoming bytes. This should let you do everything that you want with it. Again, you may want to look at some of the original code for this.

Or you can just modify the headers regardless of the danger and put a big red flag comment in the code that warns of possible issues.

Comment: Looks like what I wanted isn't really an option.  I just implemented a raw socket handler with just enough HTTP functionality to handle my limited use cases.  Not an ideal solution but it will handle the short term needs.